# Why does my array count stored in a session variable doubles?

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, phpmyadmin

I have a table which contains the following columns..

[image: database columns]

And I stored the data of that table in a session variable

```
$sql = "SELECT * from `basic_info` where Username='".$user."' and Password='".$pass."'";
$sqlresult = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($sqlresult);
$currentData = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlresult);

if($rowCount > 0){
    $_SESSION['currentUser'] = $currentData;
}
```

But whenever i echo the values of the array using below code:

```
<?php

echo "Welcome {$_SESSION['currentUser'][1]}";
echo "<div name='infoDisplay'>";
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><b>Family Name</b><td>";
echo "<td><b>First Name</b><td>";
echo "<td><b>Middle Name</b><td>";
echo "<td><b>Birthday</b><td>";
echo "<td><b>Contact Number</b><td>";
echo "<td><b>Address</b><td>";
echo "<td><b>Username</b><td>";
echo "<td><b>Password</b><td>";
echo "<td><b>Permission Level</b><td>";
echo "<td></td>";
echo "</tr>";


echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";

echo "Array count: " . count($_SESSION['currentUser']) . "<br/>";

echo "<tr>";
for($rowcount=0; $rowcount<=count($_SESSION['currentUser']);$rowcount++){
    echo "<td>". $_SESSION['currentUser'][$rowcount] . "</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";

?>
```

the array count is doubled. I only have 9 columns in my database but the result is returning 18 counts. Which why I'm also getting below error:

[image: error]

Please let me know your inputs on how can I easily resolve the issue. Thank you very much in advance! Have a great day!

Comment: `$_SESSION['currentUser'][] = $currentData;` Can there be more than one current user? Is this your actual code? The top and bottom don't really match up.

Comment: As for why you're getting double, it's because you haven't read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) which shows that by default `mysqli_fetch_array` returns both numeric and string keys, i.e. 0-n and the column names.

Comment: @JonStirling I forgot to edit that part. I already corrected the part. please ignore that line. thank you!

Comment: @JonStirling But is it suppose to display also if that's the case?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Why aren't you using $rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($sqlresult); in your for loop? That's how many times you should be looping.

Comment: You should also look at [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) rather than storing plain text password on your database. Big Security Hole

Comment: I mean the column names. If the **mysqli_fetch_array** also returns the column names, it should also display in my page right? but in my case, it is not.

Comment: I mean it gives you numeric and string _keys_. You wouldn't actually see the column names showing up on your page.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, `mysqli_fetch_array` returns an array with two elements for each column selected in the query: one element with a numeric key, and one element whose key is the column name. So if you select 9 columns, the array will have numeric keys from `0` to `8`, and named keys `FamilyName`, `FirstName`, and so on.

The problem you're running into `count($_SESSION['currentUser'])` counts both of these elements, so it will return `18`, not `9`. Your `for` loop then uses this as the limit, so it will try to echo `$_SESSION['currentUser'][9]` through `$_SESSION['currentUser'][17]`, which don't exist.

The solution to this is to use `mysql_fetch_row()` instead of `mysql_fetch_array()`. Or use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` and use a `foreach` loop instead of a `for` loop, which is my normal preference.

Answer (score 0):

> FROM THE MANUAL:
>
> mysqli_fetch_array() is an extended version of the mysqli_fetch_row() function. In addition to storing the data in the numeric indices of the result array, the mysqli_fetch_array() function can also store the data in associative indices, using the field names of the result set as keys.

So for each row you return lets say you did `select fname,lname from ...`

You would get an array for each row like this:-

```
$row would be 

[0 => 'fred', 'fname' => 'fred', 1 => 'Bloggs', 'lname' => 'Bloggs']
```

This is the doubling up of columns you are talking about

If you use

```
mysqli_fetch_array($sqlresult, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

or

```
mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlresult);
```

You will only get the Associative array of column names like :

```
['fname' => 'fred', 'lname' => 'Bloggs']
```